# GWT datepicker goes nuts under 1900

Tags: gwt, date, datepicker

I'm navigating with the month back button and when you go to year < 1900 evil things start happening.

- If you are on December and click back you go forward 23 months
- If you are on January and click back you move forward 11 months
- If you are on February it works as it should.
- So on..

I have to be able to navigate to year 1000. I have extended the datepicker class and monthselector (bug is also there if I don't extend them) so I could find some kind of a law of how the years jump and add extra years but that seems a bit silly. Does anyone know a good fix?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use your own date object most likely.  The [Java.util.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29) object was deprecated back in '97 and has a lot of very annoying traits among them being that getYear() returns "
the year represented by this date, minus 1900."  So for example:

```
Date myDate = new Date();  
int year = myDate.getYear(); //--> 111
```

On the Gwt Issues page for [Calendar Emulation](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=603&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars), several people talk about use a gwt joda-time object that is supposed to be a better Date object.  You might also be able to try that.

Comment: `java.util.Date` has **not** been deprecated.  You are perhaps confusing the deprecation of the (calendar-specific) *constructors* to `Date` with the class itself.   The class is certainly still in use and in fact acts as the underlying storage type for a `Calendar` (see `Calendar.getTime()`).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, just every getter/setter besides set/getTime() is deprecated.