# DatePicker, Date object in Java GWT returns wrong values

Tags: java, date, gwt, datepicker

The following problem is quite tenacious this week.
I try to get the date which the user selects with the following methods.

```
datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setValue(new Date(), true);
Date date = datePicker.getValue();
int year = date.getYear()+1900;
int month = date.getMonth();
int day = date.getDay();
```

All I get are strange values like for today 02/28/2013 I get 01/04/113.

I found a few things like that the methods mentioned above are depreciated and that I can just add 
1900 to the year. 
For the year adding a number would work but not for the month and the dates.

I haven't found a good solution to that problem yet.
So I anyone has a hint how this can be solved I would be really thankful for your help!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What code gets you "01/04/113"?

Comment: For which purpose you are adding 1900

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. May I know for what purpose you are adding 1900 in the year?

Answer (score 0):

Java calendar has Julian and Gregorian date component. You need not add `1900`. Remove adding of 1900 and your code should work fine. Java itself handles it by adding 1900 and further datepicker goes for a toss if its date is less than 1900.

[GWT datepicker goes nuts under 1900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829349/gwt-datepicker-goes-nuts-under-1900)

If you find this answer helpful, don't forget to upvote or even better if it solves your problem Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

That is Because you are adding 1900 that is not the Correct way to add that number Java have inbuilt Functionality to add that numbers. so From my side u need to remove that 1900 and u will able to have correct Answer that you want.

and if you are using date Picker it automatically add date of current date. so if u are adding 1900 into the current means 2013 year the it would be problem for that. and DatePicker have setting Date formate not

```
            Date date = new Date();
            datePicker1.setDate(date);
            date = datePicker1.getDate();
            int year = date.getYear();
            int day = date.getDay();
            int month = date.getMonth();
            System.out.println(year+""+day+""+month);
```